# AngularJS Функция возвращает null

Tags: angularjs

Передаю в функцию для выборки rid:

```
$scope.record = function(rid) {
                $http.post("/device/record/", {rid: rid })
                  .then(function success(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.SpisokDevice = data;
    }, function error(err) {
        console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
    });
```

Запрос `/device/record/` по факту возвращает:

```
[{"filename":"audio.mp3"}]
```

Но в консоли вижу, что на запрос вернулся пустой ответ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где я мог допустить ошибку?

Comment: _Запрос /device/record/ по факту возвращает:

`[{"filename":"audio.mp3"}]`_ - докажи

Comment: да, в callback, замени имя параметра `data`, на `response`, и для доступа к полученным данным обращайся к полю `data`: `.then(function success(response) {
        console.log(response.data);`

Comment: Не знаю точно, как у вас там все устроено, но если вы пытаетесь что-то получить, то правильнее использовать метод get, а не post.

Comment: $http.get всё возвращает как положено. Обоснуйте, почему лучше использовать его?